# How to prevent my browser scrolling to the top of the window when selecting search bar on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Been attempting to fix an annoying issue with no luck so hoping someone here can help.

On mobile, my navigation bar is fixed to the top of the page when you scroll down. The search bar is toggled by tapping the search icon on the navigation and appears directly under the nav bar.

Once the search bar is displayed, if you tap the input field to search something, the webpage jumps to the top which is quite annoying.

Tested on a iPhone 6.

Here is the link to my site: anand.nrdev.co.uk

I've tried:

```
$('body').bind('focusin focus', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

but no luck. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the search toggle is a link with a `href="#"` isn't it? If so, add a class to it to target it via jQuery like so.

```
$('a.search-toggle').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

So your search toggle button will be something to the effect of...

```
<a href="#" class="search-toggle">Search Toggle</a>
```

The reason it's jumping is (assuming it has an octothorpe (#) as the `href`) is that it's using the generic id as anchor to the top of the page. So using the example you posted in your question, you can stop it from doing that by preventing the click. You were almost right but just need to target the element itself, not the body.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the search toggle is not a link so this is not what's causing the issue.

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the search toggle please. Will need to tweak it slightly then but I need to see the markup.

Comment: Yeah certainly, i'll try replicate the issue on a fiddle during my lunch break and post back with the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand the question very well, but if you want to disable scroll while search bar is displayed add

`overflow: hidden;` to your `<body>` tag as long as search bar is displayed, hope it helps?

Here is example

```
$('#SearchbarID').toggle(function () {
    $('body').css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```